# Automation with Chrome for Testing browser version 115 - how does it work?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-for-testing

Due to changes in Chrome since version 115,
for browser automation and testing purposes, a zip file containing Chrome for Testing can be downloaded.

Please advise how it will work from version 115 with Windows?

How should I change settings for an existing project in C#?

How to change WebDriver.cs?

Is there any guidance for this?

Comment: https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/

Answer (score 2):

it looks like they've just changed the location where the ChromeDriver can be downloaded from. I found it here, where there is a zip that contains the chromedriver.exe file:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Answer (score 1):

No, that is only for chrome 115, I downloaded and no chromedriver.exe in the folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You picked up the wrong zip file, try the highlighted package instead.

[image]